# No full-size app banner :Eligibility issues by version

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am trying to publish an update to my android app and the review done by play console is rejecting the app. I have added different xhdpi icons and changed the app title as well. More than 4-5 iterations have been done.

I have already added xhdpi icons and changed the title of the icons/banners to match the app title. Added icons in the drawable folder

No specific code.

Successful app publishing.

Please refer the message

Following is the message:-
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I want to post an update here. The issue got resolved when I added the app title on the image used as a banner/icon.

I received a detailed response from Google Playstore team that my app banner/icon was not having app title which should be visible for end users trying to lauch the app from launcher.

Following was the response.

> Please note that our banner requirements are as follows:  App name
>   must be included in the image.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are targeting Android TV. Do you want to? If you do, then click on the link in the message you were sent. It will take you to the docs on [providing a Home Screen Banner inside your app](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner).

If you think you have done this then update your question to show your `AndroidManifest.xml`.