# Why is my channel image not showing on my AndroidTV/FireTV app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I have an AndroidTV/FireStick project in Android Studio, and I have my ic_banner.png in the associated drawable folders (per documentation). However, on FireStick, the channel icon shows my app icon (1:1 instead of 16:9). How do I fix this? Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="private">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:banner="@drawable/ic_banner"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.host.hostdetail.HostDetailActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.DeviceLinkActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My ic_banner.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_banner_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_banner_foreground"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Is it just because I'm sideloading via Android Studio? I just don't want to push it until I get it fixed. I've tried putting it in the mipmap folder, and nothing. It falls back to the ic_launcher icon centered in the 16:9 rectangle no matter what, and it looks AWFUL. Is there something I'm missing?

These icons are what I'm referring to.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by channel icon? Can you post a screenshot to clarify which place in the launcher you mean?

Comment: It's the 16:9 image that shows the app (when on main page). I've added a demo image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that specifying the banner you are referring, is part of the [app submission to the Appstore](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/appstore-details.html#firetvassets) and Fire TV does not use the banner specified in the app manifest. So It comes from Amazon Appstore and you may not be able to test it before submitting the app to the store.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried to submit to Google Play Console, and it is rejected for 'no full-size banner' but It's setup *exactly* like they have in the documentation. So frustrating.

Comment: @JoelHager I think that is a different problem. One of these responses may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326425/10086742 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658541/10086742